# Как скачать картинки с сайта?

Tags: python, html, парсер

Есть сайт - https://scrolller.com/
Я хочу написать скрипт на Python, который будет скачивать с сайта какое-то количество картинок, но сами картинки загружаются не в html, поэтому скачивание сайта через urllib и последующий парсинг на beautifulsoup не поможет. Есть какой-то другой способ?

Comment: Судя по логам браузера, сайт предоставляет graphql-api. Можно использовать его.

Answer (score 1):

selenium Есть хорошие уроки тут https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrWWcscvUWaqdQJLQQGO6BA